# Is there a way to get user's email address from a messenger app on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-chatbot

Is there a way to get user's email address from a messenger app on a facebook page? I realize facebook gives me page scoped IDs, but you can't get a User node based on that.

Comment: No, that is not possible. You would need to use Account Linking to first have them log in to your Facebook app (or a different one), and ask them for permission to access their email.

Answer (score 2):

No, the information you get from Facebook Messenger Platform are:

1. first_name - First name
2. last_name - Last name
3. profile_pic - Profile picture
4. locale - Locale of the user on Facebook
5. timezone - Timezone, number relative to GMT
6. gender - Gender
7. is_payment_enabled - Is the user eligible to receive messenger platform payment messages

The trouble is that FB IDs and Messenger IDs are different.